# get the selected item from second view

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have two views, each with its own view controller. The first view has two buttons ("Button" and "Button2"). When I click on "Button", I load the second view controller, which contains a `UIPickerView`, which hovers over of first view (by performing `addSubview`) as is shown in the image below). When I click on the "Item" button of this second view, I hide the view with the `UIPickerView`. When I click on the "Item" button, I not only want to hide the view with the `UIPickerView`, but also to set name of button with item selected from `UIPickerView`.

(Each of these two view has its own view controller.)

[image: screen snapshot]

Comment: If you have two view controllers, one for that main view with the two buttons, and another for the view with the picker, then you'd generall pass data back using delegate pattern, as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/9736559#9736559. If you did [the necessary custom container calls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81), you don't need an additional `delegate` property, but can reference `parentViewController`.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you only have one view controller, and you're just adding a `UIPickerView` to your view and then removing it, then The King's answer below should help.

Comment: i Have Two UiViewController.

Comment: Then (a) do the necessary containment calls; (b) your child will then have a `parentViewController` property that is set; (c) make the parent conform to some protocol that you'll use to pass the data back; and (d) use that protocol to let the child inform the parent of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is as follows:

1. Define a protocol for the child view controller to inform the parent view controller:

   ```
   //
   //  ChildViewDelegate.h
   //

   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @protocol ChildViewDelegate <NSObject>

   - (void)didUpdateValueX:(NSString *)string;

   @end
   ```

   Obviously, replace `didUpdateValueX` with a more meaningful name.
2. Define the parent view controller to conform to that protocol:

   ```
   //
   //  ViewController.h
   //

   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "ChildViewDelegate.h"

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewDelegate>

   // the rest of your interface here

   @end
   ```
3. Make sure the parent controller implements the method from that protocol:

   ```
   - (void)didUpdateValueX:(NSString *)string
   {
       // do whatever you want with it
   }
   ```
4. When the parent adds the child, make sure to call the necessary custom container calls, notably `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`:

   ```
   UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"child"];
   [self addChildViewController:controller];
   controller.view.frame = ...;
   [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
   [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   ```
5. When the child is ready to inform the parent and dismiss itself, it does something like:

   ```
   if ([self.parentViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ChildViewDelegate)])
   {
       [(id<ChildViewDelegate>)self.parentViewController didUpdateValueX:someStringValue];

       [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
       [self.view removeFromSuperview];
       [self removeFromParentViewController];
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: %@ does not conform to ChildViewDelegate!!!", __FUNCTION__, self.parentViewController);
   }
   ```

   This calls the protocol method and then removes itself (calling the necessary containment methods, `willMoveToParentViewController:nil` and `removeFromParentViewController`).

Theoretically, you could simplify this (keep all the containment stuff, but abandon the protocol) if your parent had a class property, and the child could theoretically reference that directly, but best practice is to use a protocol, so child controllers are a little more agnostic about their parent controllers.

See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide.* For a discussion about why it's important to use these container calls in the first place, see the WWDC 2011 video [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

Answer (score 0):

You can access SELECTED Value from `UIPickerView` by using...

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Following I describe Basic Step For How to Get selected Value From `UIPickerView`.

```
NSInteger selctedRow;
selctedRow = [myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *strValue = [myArrayOfPickerView objectAtIndex:selctedRow];

[myButtonName setTitle:strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**OR**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *strValue = [myArrayOfPickerView objectAtIndex:Row];
    [myButtonName setTitle:strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: But he's not just adding a picker to the view. If I read him correctly, he's got an entirely separate view controller for that contained view. So I suspect he's struggling on passing the data back to the `parentViewController`.

Comment: @Rob- OP only add UIView as Sub View OF ViewController and in subView he also added UIPickerView nothing anymore.

Comment: I read the question very differently from you (e.g. "I have two View (UiViewController)" and "each view has a controller"), but it's a little unclear, so you could well be right.

Comment: @Rob- first OP is not clear that have 2 view controller or UIView. if OP have 2 viewController then how it is possible to display two button (button and Button2) that are added in firstViewController ???

Comment: i have two ViewController and i show the second viewController with [addSubView ...]

Comment: When doing [custom container view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6), it's frequently the case that the child view controller's views do not occupy the whole screen. If you're used to the "one controller for one screen", it's a little alien, but in complicated apps, custom containers are brilliant. Frankly, it's not clear if it's needed here, though.

Comment: @Rob- thanks for you expansive information i got new today :) really thanks :)